# How do you monitor your web services?

Tags: web-services

Is there any tools that can be used to monitor SOAP, REST services for basic as well as service uptime etc.,

Comment: we have services on both windows and unix boxes. Not sure if this make a difference,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I keep track of my systems with [nagios](http://www.nagios.org/). Basically I scripted some queries to
the relevant services so that I get warnings if they don't respond properly / in reasonable time.

Answer (score 2):

In a development environment I use either the [TcpMonitor](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wpfhelp/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.bowstreet.designer.doc/designer/t_using_apache_axis_tcp_monitor.htm) that came with Apache Axis or [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) which is less invasive in the sense that you don't have to change port numbers or hostnames in your configuration.

Also, for services implemented via Java servlets, I have a filter that I can put in front of the service which logs the payload of each request and response.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) used successfully in the past.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only to monitor my suggestion is nagios (just see the other answers)
But if you want a tool to display performance data on graphs, a good one is [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/), it uses RRDTool and can help you generating graphs.
It keeps a historical graphing data.